# MySQL UNION - output two single value queries into different columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two different tables from which I want to extract the number of unique IDs. The queries for each single table look as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t1ID` FROM `table1`
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t2ID` FROM `table2` WHERE `condition`='true'
```

I would like to combine both queries into a single statement. I know I can use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t1ID` FROM `table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t2ID` FROM `table2` WHERE `condition`='true'
```

However, this outputs the two counts in two separate rows using the count name from the first query as column name:

```
+------+
+ t1ID +
+------+
+    4 +
+------+
+    5 +
+------+
```

Is there a way to get the UNION query to output the data in two columns with the corresponding count names? I.e.

```
+------+------+
+ t1ID + t2ID +
+------+------+
+    4 +    5 +
+------+------+
```

That way it would be a lot easier to directly reference the results rather than heaving to remember the order in which the queries were submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`))  FROM `table1` ) as `t1ID`,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`))  FROM `table2` WHERE `condition`='true') as `t2ID`
```

Comment: D'oh! So easy! *facepalm*

Comment: `SELCT`? --- you meant `SELECT` @PeterRing

Comment: Lifesaver answer!
Thank You @PeterRing

Answer (score 0):

```
select sub1.t1ID, sub2.t2ID
from (SELECT uniqueid, COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t1ID` FROM `table1`) sub1
join (SELECT uniqueid, COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t2ID` FROM `table2` 
      WHERE `condition`='true') sub2 on sub1.uniqueid=sub2.uniqueid
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select sum(t1ID) as t1ID
     , sum(t2ID) as t2ID
from (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t1ID`, 0 as `t2ID` FROM `table1`
     union all 
    SELECT 0 as `t1ID`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t2ID` FROM `table2` 
     WHERE `condition`='true'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(t1ID) as t1ID , sum(t2ID) as t2ID
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t1ID`, 0 as `t2ID` FROM `table1`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 as `t1ID` , COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t2ID` FROM `table2` WHERE `condition`='true'
)t
```

Make sure you put the derived table alias as I have `t` else you will get error as

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Answer (score 0):

if i guess, you want to recognize the output , and know which value from which table...

a good trick is this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t1ID`, 't1ID' as 'X' FROM `table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`uniqueid`)) as `t2ID`, 't2ID' as 'X' FROM `table2` WHERE `condition`='true'
```

adding , 't1ID' and , 't2ID' will appear as value near the count
and when reading the row, get the 2nd value (by name X) then you can know which value comes from which source.